# Getting the AudioCall in a Lync Conference via UCMA

Tags: call, lync, ucma, conference

I'm looking for a way to get a references to AudioCalls in existing conferences via a Lync UCMA application so that I can change the audio routing for participants of a conference without them having to join via a bot and setting up back-to-back calls.

Does anyone have any idea how this might be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh527751%28v=office.14%29.aspx)

> In order for a UCMA application to turn a call into a conference in this manner, however, it must be involved from the beginning. All of the messages that are passed back and forth between the two call participants in setting up the call must be routed through the UCMA application. This is because there is no way for a UCMA application to “intervene” in a two-party call where it is not a participant.

From my understanding a call to a conference is still a 2-way call, so this would be not possible. There are also some other posts on the topics of transfering calls from 1 conference to the other. One of them (i'm sure) states that when you transfer the call without a back-to-back to the other conference, you have no way of getting it back in again. So that underlines this would be not possible.

Edit - [link](http://blogs.claritycon.com/blog/2010/12/moving-calls-between-conferences-in-ucma-3-0/)

> Now, keep in mind that this process is not repeatable. When you transfer the call using AudioVideoMcuSession.BeginTransfer, you are pulling it out of the back-to-back arrangement, and your application will no longer have a handle to the call. The Call object you have will go into the Terminated state and the caller will once again become a remote participant, completely out of your grasp.

(And PLZ let me know if i'm wrong :)  )

Comment: Indeed we saw a lot of similar evidence and had to face the fact that we weren't going to be able to get a reference to any calls in a conference without routing all of the calls via a UCMA type bot which joined each participant via back-to-back calls.  Unfortunately having all participants join via a bot wasn't acceptable.

Remembering that the underlying problem was changing the audio routing of an already active conference we also tried changing the routing via SIP messages alas with little luck as we were met with configuration errors for settings no one seems to of heard of.